# Когнитивный диссонанс или правила жизни

Tags: java

Товарищи, извиняюсь сразу, может не по теме, но не знаю что это...
Хожу по собеседованиям на вакансию Junior Java Developer, решаю различные задачки на собеседованиях и понимаю, что я ничегошеньки не знаю.
Вопрос: бывают задачки, которые любой компилятор на этапе написания кода отловит. любая порядочная IDE покажет что и как не так. зачем же тогда их разрабатывали? писали бы в блокноте и беды не знали. так вот собственно вопрос - что должен знать Junior?
весь Core: дженерики и коллекции (все виды + иерархию) + многопоточность + иерархия исключений + .... (что)?

Answer (score 7):

Я бы сказал так, что не берут не потому, что не знает - я вот далеко не Junior, но из 27 тем [@huffman](/users/13648/huffman) половину точно не знаю, ну то есть знаю, но человек, который занимается этим каждый день точно уложит на обе лопатки. Штук 5-6 технологий из этого списка вообще не знаю, есть такие которые вообще первый раз в жизни увидел :) - например `AspectWerkz` - понятия не имею об чем это (даже в Гугль не полезу).

Возвращаясь к исходному топику: так вот не берут не потому, что чего то не знает, а потому, что не нравится как человек. Точно говорю. Есть такие правила:

1. Если отправил 10 резюме и не вызвали ни на одно интервью - значит резюме/CV написано неправильно
2. Если сходил на 10 интервью и нет прогресса (ну то есть не вызвали ни разу на второе интервью или там на встречу с боссом или хотя бы на полиграф) - значит вы неправильно ведете себя на интервью.

У меня друг тоже долгое время в Канаде ходил на собеседования/интервью и проч. - не брали - маялся почти полгода и уже отчаялся. По совету одного знакомого канадца постригся, побрился, выстриг ногти - с руками оторвали.

Не утверждаю, конечно, что у [@nightin_gale](/users/14292/nightin_gale) проблемы такого же рода, но подумать о своем поведении на интервью не мешало бы. Для начала подумайте - устанавливаете ли вы эмоциональный контакт с интервьюером? Ну то есть, например, вместе смеялись над чем-либо? Или хотя бы обсуждали погоду, пробки? Ну уж если обсуждали футбол или тем паче, пардон, баб - то контакт очевидно был. Только, я почему то уверен - не обсуждали.

Ну вот это и есть правило жизни, которое Junior должен себе зарубить на носу - это вам не `AspectWerkz` и не Tomcat задеплоить - это похлеще будет.

Comment: @Barmaley AspectWerkz - Simple, high-performant, dynamic, lightweight and powerful AOP for Java  http://aspectwerkz.codehaus.org на мой взгляд AOP for Java сейчас нужно знать всем, ну хотябы представлять как оно работает и где его применять.

Comment: @huffman, я конечно же знаком с AOP благодаря Spring, а вот AspectWerkz как то не удостаивался

Comment: @Barmaley, AOP в Spring совершенно убогий. Имеет смысл изучать полноценную реализацию AOP  в AspectJ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AspectJ

Comment: @huffman - это уже холивар :)

Comment: @Barmaley, не выдержал -)

Comment: @huffman - ага ;) - вижу, что гуглем пользоваться умеете )))

Comment: @Barmaley, это очень важный навык -)

Answer (score 5):

избитая тема.

Вот примерный список того, что должен знать нормальный джавист:

1. OOA, OOD, gof и j2ee паттерны, свободное чтение УМЛ (особенно диаграммы классов, объектов, взаимодействия и состояния).
2. Нужно знать все базовые библиотеки (коллекции, сериализации, потоки ввода-вывода, работа с сеткой, рефлекшн, обработка событий, неблокирующий ввод-вывод, локализацию и т.п.). Особенно многопоточность!
3. Нужно понимать как работают виртуальная машина, загрузка классов, сборка мусора. Желательно знать базовые инструкции байт-кода.
4. Нужно уметь создавать апплеты и приложения на AWT, Swing и SWT. Естественно, и компонентную модель Java beans для элементов управления.
5. JDBC и какой-нибудь ОРМ, например Hibernate или JDO. Естественно понимать как такое отображение влияет на взаимодействие прикладных объектов и основные грабли с производительностью.
6. Java security (загрузка классов, верификация байт кода, полиси и пермишны, подписывание кода, сигнатуры, ключи и т.п.). Конечно же освоить следующие апи: JAAS, JCE, JSSE, JGSS.
7. Сервлеты, JSP, JSTL. (маленький такой пунктик)
8. Фреймворки для создания веб-приложений: Struts, JSF, Tapestry, Cocoon и т.п. Конечно же MVC должен быть на уровне рефлексов.
9. Tomcat, как туда деплоить и как поддерживать веб-приложения.
10. RMI, манипуляция удалёнными объектами.
11. Jini, технология создания распределённых приложений.
12. Парсинг XML, желательно попробовать SAX и все три апи (DOM, JDOM, DOM4J). Создание преобразований XSLT (синтаксис, семантика, часто-используемые конструкции и идиомы).
13. Веб-сервисы. Изучить JAX-RPC, SAAJ, JAXB, JAXM, JAXR. Конечно же Axis как одну из самых распространённых имплементаций SOAP.
14. Изучить лёгковесные фреймворки: Spring, Pico/NanoContainer. Знать что такое IoC и как он влияет на архитектуру.
15. Незаметный пунктик: J2EE. Разумеется не получится пройти мимо JNDI, JMS, JTA, JMX и javamail.
16. Знать, как конфигурить J2EE аппликейшн сервер, например JBOSS. Как использовать его встроенные сервисы (например, кластеризация, пулы коннекшнов, поддержку распределённых транзакций). Конечно же как деплоить/ундеплоить приложения туда, как настраивать производительность.
17. Понимать Аспектно-Ориентированное программирование. Умело распознавать границы применимости, и применять с использованием AspectJ.
18. То же самое для Атрибутно-Ориентированного программирования и AspectWerkz.
19. Знать следующие небольшие, но очень полезные фреймворки: Log4j (логгинг, трейсинг), Quartz (расписания), JCache (распределённое кэширование), Lucene (текстовый поиск) и т.д. Конечно же знать список того, что лежит в Jakarta Commons и для чего оно нужно.
20. Взаимодействие с нативным кодом — JNI, JCA.
21. Процесс формирования стандартов JCP и самые распространённые JSR.
22. Свободно владеть средами IntelliJ IDEA и Eclipse. Знать сочетания клавиш для самых распространённых операций (автодополнение, поиск/замена, рефакторинг: поменять имя, и т.п.).
    Ещё нужно освоить vim и emacs (особенно в случае работы в терминале).
23. Java достаточно многословна, поэтому обязательно изучить как генерить код с помощью XDoclet и XSLT.
24. JUnit. Как говорил Брюс Эккель — strong testing, not strong typing. Обязательно.
25. Инструменты для сборки: ant и maven. Не менее обязательно.
26. Освоить технологии производства ПО: RUP, XP, TDD и другие гибкие технологии.
27. Элемент списка

Взято с какого-то форума, сейчас уже не помню.

Исходя из выше казанного списка я бы вам порекомендовал изучить пункты: 2, 3, 12,13(хотя бы иметь предстваление),14, 17(хотя бы знать зачем оно и где применять),19(хотябы log4j),22(Eclipse, IDEA)25. (хотябы ant),

Comment: это точно для джуниора?

Comment: @nightin_gale Вы же понимаете, что каждый работодатель хочет сеньора по цене джуниора :)

Comment: человек, знающий это все по-вашему junior? Этак вы никогда себе программиста не наймете, особенно при нынешнем кадровом голоде. Думаю, человек, соответствующий всем этим критериям (и даже половине из них) просто покрутит у виска пальцем, услышав ваше предложение устроиться к нему джуниором.

Comment: @DreamChild, вы читать умеет? В начале сообщения черным по белому написано: "Вот примерный список того, что должен знать нормальный джавист:" Где там хоть слово про junior?  Список привел для того, чтобы было понято, что нужно изучать и куда стремиться. Какими скилами должен обладать junior каждый работодатель решает сам. Зайдите на сайты hh.ru или superjobs сами все увидите.

Comment: @huffman хорошо, тогда в чем вообще смысл данного списка, если ТС пока еще не "нормальный джавист", а даже не junior? Человеку бы работу надо найти, а вы его грузите тем, что его ждет (а может и не ждет) в будущем. А в ответ на то, "какими скилами должен обладать junior" (что по сути и является вопросом данной темы) вы почему-то отправляете на hh

Comment: @DreamChild, вы вместо того чтобы тут со мной спорить взяли бы и дали развернутый ответ -)

Comment: @huffman да я как раз и собираюсь это сделать) Еще чуть-чуть, и уже рожу несколько глупых мыслей)

Answer (score 5):

Начнем с того, что это может зависеть от ваших зарплатных требований. Не секрет, что нынче программисты в цене, а потому зачастую бывает так, что даже ни дня не проработавший человек требует существенную сумму. В общем, присмотритесь к своим финансовым ожиданиям. Если вы просите 70-80 тыр, то будьте готовы к тому, что с вас будут требовать знание списка, предложенного [[@huffman](/users/13648/huffman)](/users/13648/huffman)'ом.

Если вас устраивают куда более скромные суммы,  то могу вас обрадовать - каких-то особых знаний с вас не потребуется. Вполне логично предположить, что  от вас потребуются уверенные навыки программирования, знакомство с ООП, основы работы с IDE (скорее всего не очень важно с какой именно), какие-нибудь базовые знания по SQL и паре-тройке сопутствующих джаве технологий. Если посмотреть вакансии junior-разработчиков, то зачастую можно увидеть, что там почти ничего не говорится о специфических технологиях и навыках, а больше требуются "молодые, талантливые, целеустремленные, способные к самостоятельному обучению"  и всё такое в этом духе. И это в принципе логично - для начинающего программиста человеческие качества подчас даже важнее знаний, так как целеустремленность и ответственность  "изучаются" сложнее, чем условное ООП.

Также соглашусь с [[@Barmaley](/users/5648/barmaley)](/users/5648/barmaley) - приятное внешнее впечатление и общая адекватность/сообразительность кандидата могут сыграть куда большую роль, чем ваши знания (все равно на работе их потребуется серьезно дополнять, шлифовать и пересматривать)

Что касается всяческих каверзных вопросов, то лучше было бы, чтобы вы привели пример пары-тройки вопросов с собеседований. Может быть и так, что у вас слабые знания языка (да-да, несмотря на все вышесказанное, про целеустремленность и желание учиться знания Java Java-программисту тоже не помешают). Могу посоветовать [вот этот сайт](http://www.quizful.net/test), тут есть подборка весьма неплохих тестов и вопросов собеседований в том числе и по Java. Это позволит вам узнать ваш уровень и в случае чего что-то подтянуть. Из недостатков этого сервиса могу отметить, что иногда там попадаются вопросы "на внимательность" или требуется "поработать компилятором", что может несколько раздражать

Comment: спасибо всем, товарищи!
я так понял, что у меня слабые знания
по зарплате - согласен на 50 уже, лишь бы научили.
опыт как разработчика - порядка 4-х лет, но не на яве.
с SQL вроде дружу.
вид и поведение - еще никто не жаловался (прическа нормальная, ногти грызу =) )
список с квиза видел и тесты на основы Явы проходил: (10 из 20) пока лучшая попытка (заваливаюсь постоянно на невнимательности)
еще раз спасибо! иду читать Хорстмана...)

Comment: Извините, но если вы всего лишь 10 из 20 по основам еле выбиваете, то я бы вас и за 30 вряд ли взял бы. Ничего личного. Так что подтягивайте знания и корректируйте аппетиты. И еще, опыт 4 года что в себя включает? Какие языки/технологии, что за проекты, где работали, если не секрет? Я надеюсь, это именно 4 года опыта работы, а не "4 года занимаюсь программированием"?

Comment: @nightin_gale, с такими скилами вам работодателю еще доплачивать придется.

Comment: @nightin_gale 10 из 20 - это действительно ни о чём

Comment: только камнями не закидайте) я прекрасно и сам вижу, что 10 из 20 это ни о чем. 4 года - программировал на Delphi и C++. Фрэймворки почти и не использовал. Писал запросы на SQL и даже простенькие БД делал. В полном цикле разработки не участвовал никогда. Кидали несложные задачи - делал. Вроде как бы программками пользуются (десктопные и не промышленные). Жалобы до меня не доходили (уверен, они есть).
Вот щас сдал тест по основам. Я конечно дико извиняюсь, но у Эккеля, которого я прочел, не было указания, что java.lang.Math - final, а в вопросе в тесте было.

Comment: Я так понял составители - любители теории из Хорстмана. Читаю его и нахожу там многие вопросы. Я ни в коем случае не спорю, что знание теории - плохо. Но не из голой же теории состоит разработка ПО.
Ладно, извините... Просто глупо учить в отрыве от практики. А при приеме на работу требуют именно "промышленное программирование".
Помню в моем городе было обязательное требование - опыт работы - не менее 5 лет. Прям таки вундеркиндов ВТУЗы рождают: вышка и раб.опыт= ) Еще раз спасибо (и за видео спасибо)! Иду зубрить)

Comment: @nightin_gale, это стандартная практика, когда утилитарные классы, имеющие одни лишь `static` методы, помечается как `final` и имеют приватный конструктор.

Comment: @nightin_gale я неспроста спросил, что  включали в себя эти 4 года. Если вы не работали на настоящей работе, то по сути эти 4 года равны нулю. Не то что бы это бесполезный опыт, но опытом работы уж точно не назвать. А есть если человек не имеет опыта работы и при этом говорит "ну так уж и быть, давайте ваши 50, согласен", то у многих потенциальных работодателей это вызовет подсознательное (и совершенно справедливое) желание указать соискателю на дверь. Не исключаю, что при нынешнем кадровом голоде вы сможете найти работу за эти деньги, однако если умерите аппетиты, то найдёте наверняка.

Comment: Более того, если вы начнете с меньших сумм, но покажете себя с положительной стороны, то скорее всего через полгода  станете получать существенно больше.

Comment: >Я ни в коем случае не спорю, что знание теории - плохо. Но не из голой же теории состоит разработка ПО

Чтобы быть хорошим разработчиком, знание подобных аспектов необходимо. Это во-первых. Во-вторых, не секрет, что на собеседованиях часто спрашивают о том, с чем разработчик может не столкнуться на практике вообще. Скажем, большинство программистов никогда не сталкивались с необходимостью знать, как работает сборщик мусора, однако вопросы о нем на многих собеседованиях появляются с завидным постоянством. Однако такие знания позволяют глубже понимать и лучше использовать сам язык

Comment: да я уже готов работать за еду) шутка, конечно, но понимаю, что действительно скорее всего я и не работал... просто хочется освоить Яву через практику... а вакансий джуниора или стажера на hh я почти не вижу.... = (

Answer (score 0):

Тут уже многое сказано, я просто добавлю доклад одного очень крутого человека. Он как раз рассказывает в этом докладе о поиске работы, поиске первой работы и т.д.. Посмотрите, мне в своё время помогло проанализировать свои ошибки, а они так же были :)

[Как стать профессиональным Java разработчиком](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ft0Nj8Cm9kk)